# Textbox ContextMenu localization

Tags: wpf, localization, textbox

How to localize default context menu items of a WPF TextBox? I mean the Cut, Copy and Paste texts.

Regards,

Jawahar

Comment: Localization in WPF can be a pain, and there is no convenient way to do it out of the box. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Resx_Localization.aspx) gives a pretty good solution, but I'm afraid it doesn't mention anything on localizing default context menu items.

Answer (score 2):

I think WPF picks the Locale installed on your Machine (.net Language Pack).
If you want to customize the context Menu, you must create your own.